# How to convert a numpy array to greyscale image?

Tags: image, numpy, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I am trying to convert an 8-by-8 numpy array of binary format (0 represents black and 1 represents white). This is what I run:

```
from PIL import Image

data = im.fromarray(array)     # array is an 8*8 binary numpy
data.save('dummy_pic.png')
```

But in the output I get a fully black square. Could anyone give me a hand please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black square is probably very dark gray, because you may have `np.array` with `uint8` datatype, which has range of 0-255, not 0-1 like binary array. Try changing array datatype to `bool`, or scale values to 0-255 range.

Here is code snippet in which binary array is generated and displayed. If you scale by smaller value, circle will become slightly darker.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Generating binary array which represents circle
radius = 0.9
size = 100
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,size),np.linspace(-1,1,size))
f = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: ( 1.0 if x*x + y*y < radius*radius else 0.0))
array = f(x,y)

# Solution 1: 
# convert np.array to bool datatype
array = (array).astype(np.bool)

# Solution 2:
# scale values to uint8 maximum 255
array = ((array) * 255).astype(np.uint8)


img = Image.fromarray(array)
display(img)
```

Result: [White circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIO41.png)